# problemas al obtner un resultado de un arreglo con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas para obtener un resultado de ese arreglo donde quiero obtener un resultado igual

```
{name: 'Aguas', type: 'column',data: [0, 0, 10080, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45382,123.764] }
```

donde data son los meses en que tengo monto pagado acumulado por mes si en ese no hay pago corresponde 0 se debe colocar en el mismo orden de meses desde diciembre 2019 hasta enero 2020 .
si me pueden ayudar le agradeceria lo quiero asi para pasarle la infomacion un grafico
donde data son los meses en que tengo monto pagado acumulado por mes si en ese no hay pago corresponde 0 se debe colocar en el mismo orden de meses desde diciembre 2019 hasta enero 2020 .
si me pueden ayudar le agradeceria lo quiero asi para pasarle la infomacion un grafico

```
let array = [{
     "Anho": 2019,
     "Mes": "December",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2019,
     "Mes": "November",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "October",
     "NombreRubro": "Celular",
     "MontoPagado": "5000",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "September",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2019,
     "Mes": "October",
     "NombreRubro": "Agua",
     "MontoPagado": "10080",
     "CantidadPago": 1
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2019,
     "Mes": "October",
     "NombreRubro": "Agua",
     "MontoPagado": "22691",
     "CantidadPago": 1
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "August",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "July",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "June",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "May",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "April",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "March",
     "NombreRubro": "",
     "MontoPagado": "0",
     "CantidadPago": 0
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "February",
     "NombreRubro": "Agua",
     "MontoPagado": "45382",
     "CantidadPago": 2
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Agua",
     "MontoPagado": "32950",
     "CantidadPago": 4
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Agua",
     "MontoPagado": "90764",
     "CantidadPago": 4
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Educacion",
     "MontoPagado": "45382",
     "CantidadPago": 2
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Educacion",
     "MontoPagado": "204246",
     "CantidadPago": 2
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Luz",
     "MontoPagado": "22691",
     "CantidadPago": 1
 },
 {
     "Anho": 2020,
     "Mes": "January",
     "NombreRubro": "Luz",
     "MontoPagado": "25000",
     "CantidadPago": 1
 }
```

];

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? No esperarás que lo hagamos por ti. Saludos

Comment: A lo que se refiere @MauricioContreras es que tu pregunta es muy abierta, te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic para conocer mejor cómo realizar una pregunta en el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por la poca información que brindas y lo que he entendido, esto es lo que se me ocurrió, así que en principio probablemente sea algo ineficiente.

No sé cuál sea el origen de los datos, pero tal vez te sea más útil la propiedad `Mes` como valor numérico que como cadena.

Lo primero que se hace es filtar de todos los datos, aquellos que cumplan con tu condición:

- `NombreRubro`: `Agua`
- `Anho`: `2019`

Luego puedes iterar sobre el resultado para obtener las cantidades y sumarlos a los acumulados del mes correspondiente, que previamente han sido inicializados en 0.

Como bien dije al incio, esto en principio podría ser ineficiente, pero te puede servir como base para mejorar el proceso. Podrías cambiar el método de filtrado y reducción e incluso llevarlo a una función para que tú le pases los parámetros de búsqueda que necesitas.

```js
const array = [
  {
    Anho: 2019,
    Mes: 'December',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2019,
    Mes: 'November',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'October',
    NombreRubro: 'Celular',
    MontoPagado: '5000',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'September',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2019,
    Mes: 'October',
    NombreRubro: 'Agua',
    MontoPagado: '10080',
    CantidadPago: 1,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2019,
    Mes: 'October',
    NombreRubro: 'Agua',
    MontoPagado: '22691',
    CantidadPago: 1,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'August',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'July',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'June',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'May',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'April',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'March',
    NombreRubro: '',
    MontoPagado: '0',
    CantidadPago: 0,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'February',
    NombreRubro: 'Agua',
    MontoPagado: '45382',
    CantidadPago: 2,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Agua',
    MontoPagado: '32950',
    CantidadPago: 4,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Agua',
    MontoPagado: '90764',
    CantidadPago: 4,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Educacion',
    MontoPagado: '45382',
    CantidadPago: 2,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Educacion',
    MontoPagado: '204246',
    CantidadPago: 2,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Luz',
    MontoPagado: '22691',
    CantidadPago: 1,
  },
  {
    Anho: 2020,
    Mes: 'January',
    NombreRubro: 'Luz',
    MontoPagado: '25000',
    CantidadPago: 1,
  },
];

const meses = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
];

const pagoAgua = array.filter(
  value => value.NombreRubro === 'Agua' && value.Anho === 2019
);

const acumulados = Array(12).fill(0);
console.log(acumulados);

pagoAgua.forEach(pago => {
  acumulados[meses.indexOf(pago.Mes)] += +pago.MontoPagado;
});

console.log(acumulados);
```

Comment: Justo asi me sirve amigo gracias